# Using matplotlib.pyplot for plotting array acquired from numpy.savetxt function

Tags: numpy, matplotlib

I am trying to plot aggregated radar rainfall hourly data. I used np.savetxt to save the aggregated file in .asc format. Now, I am using matplot.pyplot to show the aggregated rainfall. However, I am getting the following error :

```
type object got multiple values for keyword argument 'transform' <Figure size 432x288 with 2 Axes>
```

The code is as below:

```
import os
from hrap_to_latlon import hrap_to_latlon
import numpy as N
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from cartopy.mpl.ticker import LongitudeFormatter, LatitudeFormatter
import cartopy.crs as ccrs`inpath= 'D:/UTA/JunaidData/2011-2017/2016/Testfiles24/'
output= 'D:/UTA/JunaidData/2011-2017/2016/Output/'

 files = os.listdir(inpath)
 SUM_UP=N.zeros((nrows,ncols),dtype=N.float, order='C',)
 for i in files: 

     outfile = (output +'MRMS'+'06'+ i[6:8] + '2016' +i[-3:-1]+'z')
     mpe=N.genfromtxt(outfile+'.asc', delimiter=" ", skip_header=6, unpack=False)/25.4
     mpe_masked = N.ma.masked_less(mpe, 0.01)
     mpeflip=N.flipud(mpe)
     SUM_UP=SUM_UP+mpeflip
 Final = N.savetxt ('.asc', SUM_UP, fmt='%.18e', delimiter='', newline='\n', header='', 
 footer='', comments='# ', encoding=None) 
 plt.figure(Final) 
 ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())`
 nws_precip_colors = [
"#fdfdfd",   # 0.00 - 0.01 inches
"#04e9e7",  # 0.01 - 0.10 inches
"#019ff4",  # 0.10 - 0.25 inches
"#0300f4",  # 0.25 - 0.50 inches
"#02fd02",  # 0.50 - 0.75 inches
"#01c501",  # 0.75 - 1.00 inches
"#008e00",  # 1.00 - 1.50 inches
"#fdf802",  # 1.50 - 2.00 inches
"#e5bc00",  # 2.00 - 2.50 inches
"#fd9500",  # 2.50 - 3.00 inches
"#fd0000",  # 3.00 - 4.00 inches
"#d40000",  # 4.00 - 5.00 inches
"#bc0000",  # 5.00 - 6.00 inches
"#f800fd",  # 6.00 - 8.00 inches
"#9854c6"  # 8.00 + inches
]
precip_colormap = matplotlib.colors.ListedColormap(nws_precip_colors)

levels = [0.00, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 8.0, 10.0, 12.0, 14.0, 16.0, 18.0, 20.0, 22.0, 24.0, 48.0, 
96.0]
norm = matplotlib.colors.BoundaryNorm(levels, 14)

ax_color=ax.pcolormesh(nx_coord,ny_coord, mpe_masked, shading='nearest', norm=norm, 
cmap=precip_colormap, transform=ccrs.PlateCarree(), zorder=1) #cividis_r
cb=plt.colorbar(ax_color)
plt.figtext(0.825, 0.89, "mm", fontsize="medium")

ax.set_extent([-98, -96.0, 32.0, 33.5], ccrs.PlateCarree())
[-97.4, -96.9, 32.4, 32.9]
ax.set_extent([-97.6, -97, 32.6, 33], ccrs.PlateCarree())
lon_ticks = [-96, -97, -98]
lat_ticks = [32, 33, 33.5]
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(LongitudeFormatter())
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(LatitudeFormatter())
ax.set_xticks(lon_ticks, crs=ccrs.PlateCarree())
ax.set_yticks(lat_ticks, crs=ccrs.PlateCarree())
```

Would appreciate the help. Thanks

Comment: Show the full error message - with traceback.

Comment: File "C:\Users\Junaid\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\image.py", line 131, in _draw_list_compositing_images
    a.draw(renderer)

  File "C:\Users\Junaid\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py", line 41, in draw_wrapper
    return draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\Junaid\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cartopy\mpl\feature_artist.py", line 213, in draw
    c = matplotlib.collections.PathCollection(paths,

TypeError: type object got multiple values for keyword argument 'transform'

<Figure size 432x288 with 2 Axes>

Comment: So what is the argument to the `transform` keyword?  `ccrs.PlateCarree()`?  I don't know what `ccrs` is or produces.  You have the code - do some basic debugging yourself.